# Can I use a generic handler to process requests differently based on url path?

Tags: c#

Say for example I have a generic handler - ~/handler.ashx -  that processes requests to a url via rewrite,  https://www.somedomain.com/foo/bar and spits out an xml response in one format, can I have the same handler respond to requests to /bar/foo in another xml format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. A Generic Handler is absolutely free to generate whatever response it wants. The hint is in the name: "Handler" (as opposed to "Filter" or "Module", as in `IHttpModule` vs `IHttpHandler`).

You will need to access and parse the original URL yourself, of course, as Generic Handlers predate ASP.NET routing. You can get it via the `HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL` server variable (I believe `Request.RawUrl` also contains it, but I don't know if this always guaranteed).

```
static readonly Regex _routeX = new Regex("foo/(.+)", RegexOptions.Compiled );
static readonly Regex _routeY = new Regex("baz/(.+)"/qux, RegexOptions.Compiled );

public void HandleRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    if( _routeX.IsMatch( context.Request.RawUrl ) )
    {
        context.Response.Write("<xml><myObject>foo</myObject></xml>");
    }
    else if( _routeY.IsMatch( context.Request.RawUrl ) )
    {
        context.Response.Write("<anotherXmlFile>baz</anotherXmlFile>");
    }
}
```

That said - this is probably a bad design because the handler is responsible for two different business tasks. Is there a reason you can't do it with separate handlers - or even ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Web API?

Comment: I'm very new at c#, and the web application I'm working with is using web forms. My reference point is some old code.